# PC,linux and Mac module not loaded in unity build settings

Tags: unity-game-engine, build-settings

I have encountered a problem that PC, Linux and Mac module is not loaded in Unity.
I have installed the whole Unity3D engine and now I have to load the PC and Linux module.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: use Unity3D download manager to download and install missing modules.

Comment: More info here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/5-3-released.372567/page-2#post-2414948